# SDWebImage without ssl certificate

Tags: ios, tvos, sdwebimage

I try to set image via SDWebImage. But SDWebImage cancel operation. I've tried to get this image in Safari with url and Safari asked me about certificate. When I cancel dialog window I get this image.

Question is: Can I disable SDWebImage certificate validation without modifying this library?

Comment: search about SDWebImageDownloaderAllowInvalidSSLCertificates in SDWebImage

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that by I've already used kingfisher as alternative.

Comment: With SDWebImageDownloaderAllowInvalidSSLCertificates still not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've spend a lot of time to drill into SDWebImage code and find solution. I wonder why docs doesn't say explicitly how to do that!

Here is the sample code:

```
NSURL *url = ... <image url here>
UIImageView *imageView = ...
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageAllowInvalidSSLCertificates progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
        CGFloat percentage = ((CGFloat)receivedSize)/((CGFloat)expectedSize);
        //Track progress here if needed. 
    } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        ...
    }];
```

The key moment is to pass `SDWebImageAllowInvalidSSLCertificates` option. Internally, this option will be transformed into proper option for shared image downloader.

Hope that helps and hope i'll be able to find my answer next time i face the issue again!

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
UIImageView_name.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: logo), placeholderImage: nil, options: .allowInvalidSSLCertificates)
```

Instead of

```
UIImageView_name.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: logo))
            UIImageView_name
```

For UIButton use

```
UIButton_name.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: customer.getProfilePic()), for: .normal, placeholderImage: nil, options: .allowInvalidSSLCertificates, completed: nil)
```